# Не компилируется скрипт с помощью PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyinstaller

Установлен `Python 3.6.0`, `PyQt 4.8.6` и `PyInstaller 3.2.1`.

Создан простой скрипт с использованием PyQt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore


class QuitButton(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')

        quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
        quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)
        self.connect(quit, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), QtGui.qApp, QtCore.SLOT('quit()'))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
qb = QuitButton()
qb.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

quit = QtGui.QPushButton('Close', self)
quit.setGeometry(10, 10, 60, 35)
```

Он запускается и вообще не представляет из себя ничего сложного, просто тест.
Выполняю `pyinstaller qt_core.py`:

```
113 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.2.1
113 INFO: Python: 3.6.0
116 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.14393-SP0
118 INFO: wrote C:\pyqt_try\qt_core.spec
120 INFO: UPX is not available.
123 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\pyqt_try', 'C:\\pyqt_try']
124 INFO: checking Analysis
126 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
127 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
130 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
134 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==3.2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 788, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 161, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 317, in assemble
    excludes=self.excludes, user_hook_dirs=self.hookspath)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 560, in initialize_modgraph
    graph.import_hook(m)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1509, in import_hook
    source_package, target_module_partname, level)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1661, in _find_head_package
    target_module_headname, target_package_name, source_package)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 209, in _safe_import_module
    module_basename, module_name, parent_package)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2077, in _safe_import_module
    module_name, file_handle, pathname, metadata)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2167, in _load_module
    self._scan_code(m, co, co_ast)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2585, in _scan_code
    module, module_code_object, is_scanning_imports=False)
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2831, in _scan_bytecode
    global_attr_name = get_operation_arg_name()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 2731, in get_operation_arg_name
    return module_code_object.co_names[co_names_index]
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Если бы отсутствовал модуль какой-то из PyQt вывод консоли был бы другим. Здесь же что то совсем не ясное. Пожалуйста помогите.

Comment: Возможно это потому что PyInstaller [не поддерживает](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2286) питон 3.6

Comment: @Flowneee спасибо. На сайте явно не указано, не нашел информации о несовместимости.

Answer (score 1):

Если взять "current developement code" со странички http://www.pyinstaller.org/, то ошибка генерации исчезнет. Только вот при запуске сгенерированного exe вылезает ошибка, что некая Qt5Svg.dll от QT 5.8 отсутствует. Победить не смог, может, Вам повезет с предыдущей версией PyQT.

Вот так все работает:

```
git clone https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller.git
cd pyinstaller
git pull origin +refs/pull/2403/merge
pip install --force-reinstall .
```

См. [это обсуждение](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2455#issuecomment-279270584)

Comment: слышал об этом. Поставил `DEV` версию, пока что неуспешно. Не люблю танцы с бубном, подожду официального релиза для `Python 3.6`.

Comment: См. мой исправленный ответ...

Comment: очень рад что Вы решили проблему. Но моей проблемы данный способ не решает, прежде всего потому что я использую PyQt4, не 5. У меня совсем другие ошибки.

Comment: я скажу даже больше. Все ошибки при компиляции я поборол, но в итоге приложение не функционирует. Запускает `cmd` и закрывается. Для меня не проблема, подождать официального релиза для `Python 3.6`.

Comment: Решил было я проверить, что там у Вас происходит, но не сумел поставить PyQt4 на 64-bit Python 3.6 Windows 7. Pip очень странно отругался: 

D:\>pip install PyQt4
Collecting PyQt4
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt4 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for PyQt4

Comment: Поставил PyQt4-4.11.4-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl c http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, developement версию PyInstaller с гитхаба (см. рецепт выше), все отработало.  Единственная разница с Вами - у меня Windows 7.

Comment: ну что ж, может и в версии `Win` проблема, не могу знать. Ошибок при компиляции нет. Проверял на примере приведенном в шапке, приложение не запускается хоть убей. Менять версию `Qt` и `Win` не намерен. Плюсик за ответ я Вам уже поставил :)

Comment: кстати, в приведенной вами инструкции необходимо заменить `pip install --force-reinstall` на `setup.py install`, или я чего то не знаю?

Comment: По поводу setup install или pip install, я взял команду из приведенного обсуждения ошибки на github.com. И рекомендую также создать issue в проекте pyinstaller на гитхабе. А то, кроме Вас и меня, никто о ней не знает. Ну и кто мешает поставить уже собранный PyQt 4.11 в virtual environment?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).
PyInstaller **не** поддерживает python 3.6

Comment: я в курсе о `cx_Freeze`. Спасибо. Но вопрос здесь не о нем. Поддержка `Python 3.6` в планах, над ней работают, и правильный ответ - подождите выхода `PyInstaller` для `Python 3.6`.

Конечно ради сообщества `SO` можно и закрыть вопрос.

Comment: @ВАНЕЧКА, вы не обязаны закрывать вопрос "ради сообщества". Правильным ответом стоит отмечать тот ответ, который помог именно вам. Или не отмечать никакой, если никакой не помог. Или дать свой ответ, и отметить его правильным.